# Color of links not always showing correctly

Tags: css, hyperlink

This is my CSS:

```
/* Navigation Bar */
#linkBar
{
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    height:24px;
    width:999px;
    background:#990033;
}

.linkbar ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.linkbar li
{
    float:left;
}
.linkbar a:link,a:visited
{
    font-size: 14px;
    display:block;
    width:134px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#990033;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.linkbar a:hover,a:active
{
    background-color:#000000;
}

/* Links */
a:link,a:visited,a:active
{
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#990033;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:hover
{
    color:#0000FF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

My expected outcome is that links show like:

[image: Normal links]

[image: Linkbar]

Which is the case for most of the elements, however the first link on the linkbar ends up like:

[image: Wrong]

Linkbar code:

```
<div id="linkBar" class="linkbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="course.php">Course</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goldfishdancer/GpZr8/) for this
(on jsfiddle i dont get the problem with the first link in the linkbar, so this implies its a problem with the rest of my code?).

I can solve the issue with the navbar if i just change the css around to be:

```
#linkBar
{
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    height:24px;
    width:999px;
    background:#990033;
}

/* Links */
a:link,a:visited,a:active
{
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#990033;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:hover
{
    color:#0000FF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* Navigation Bar */
.linkbar ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.linkbar li
{
    float:left;
}
.linkbar a:link,a:visited
{
    font-size: 14px;
    display:block;
    width:134px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#990033;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.linkbar a:hover,a:active
{
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

But this then means that the visited normal links text color is white - which is not what I want (as some normal links are on light or white backgrounds).

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goldfishdancer/AMrwC/) for this (visited links being white).

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong / point me in the direction of how to fix it?

Comment: I don't see any rule that shows the text color being white .. can you show us an example, perhaps on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: .linkbar a:link,a:visited - color:#FFFFFF is the only place that makes the text color white. Writing an example of jsfiddle now.

Comment: added jsfiddle links to original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have written `.linkbar a:link,a:visited` you need to repeat the classname before `a:visited`

Right now you are actually saying '.linkbar link, and then override all a:visited'

So it should be `.linkbar a:link, .linkbar a:visited { .. }`